# Why am I only able to get certain links in tweets?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm making a program that takes in a Twitter username and returns all of the external links a user shared. So far the program returns some links, but not others, even among tweets linking to the same website.

I've recognized that the problem is that for the tweets that do return external links as desired, the external link is the "expanded_url" attribute of the tweet. For the tweets that don't return the external link, the "expanded_url" attribute is just the link to the tweet itself.

Anyone know why this is? Is there any way around this?

I'm using Tweepy and the "expanded URL" attribute.

For example, these two similar tweets:

https://twitter.com/KamalaHarris/status/1079137488378183681

https://twitter.com/KamalaHarris/status/1077337876227084290

The first one returns the URL to the article. 
The second one does not.

Answer (score 2):

Update for anyone curious: Adding `tweet_mode="extended"` to my search term seemed to do the trick!